# Accidentally checked out svn in my user folder and not it is full of php/html/svn files

Tags: svn

Is there a way to revert checkout of svn repo?

I accidentally checked out huge codebase in my user folder, and it will be really pain to delete everything out manually, is there a way to remove it?

I'm talking about removing working copy...

Comment: What OS are you using? Can't you just delete the N newest files?

Comment: @terdon I'm on mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn ls` will show you the versioned files and folders in the current working directory.

To automate removal of versioned files, you can run the following:

```
svn update --set-depth empty
```

This will *set* the working copy depth to `empty`, meaning that all future update operations will not checkout anything. This also causes all already versioned files not in the given depth (i.e. all of them) to be deleted locally.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with `svn` so I am not sure if checked out files keep their original timestamp. Assuming they do not, the checked out files will all have been created at the same time on your system. You should then be able to remove them either by sorting by date on `finder` or from the command line with `find`.

If you want to delete all files and folders created less than 24 hours ago:

```
find . -mtime -1 -delete
```

You can also use `-mmin` for minutes. Have a look at `man find` and [here](https://superuser.com/a/518326/151431) for more information.

If the situation is more complex and simple timestamps will not do, you can try checking out the files into another directory, listing the files created and then deleting files with the same name from the original directory.

```
mkdir newdir; cd new dir
svn co http://svn.url.com
for n in $(find . ); do rm "/old_dir/$n"; done
```

This will list all files checked out (`find .`) and delete them sequentially.

Comment: The first approach does not work if SVN's `use-commit-times = yes` is set.